# Question related to Shipping Adress and registeration

Tags: checkout, shipping-address

How can I disable the editing of Shipping address by a customer once he registers on my site?
And it should auto select if am logged in to the site and moves to the checkout

Comment: you can hide `Edit address` button in my account page....

Comment: Will it autogenerated or fetched from database automatically  when am purchasing something and

Comment: placing the order

Comment: i guess if customer selected checkbox below the address `save address` it will be saved when buying, it will be better if you do real time test once in site also,  not sure why you want to remove `edit option` for customer.....

Comment: I want to save the shipping address when user registers to the site and when they purchase something the address should be fetched from the site so that I will provide the change of shipping address for "Send the product as Gift " functionality only

Comment: than you dont want to provide any option for customer to change address ?  okay than if customer changed their address & than if there is no option for him to change shipping address he dont buy the product , also again he may neeed to create another account for new shipping address, dont you think it may affect on `number of orders` ?

Comment: I have one more question - I am using subscription extension for certain product, like 3moths and six months and want to integrate reward points extension for the customer who buys the subscription for the first time.But am unable to understand how this flow will work

Comment: sorry, i really have dont have much idea about those 2 extensions, may be `google` will help you or please post new question for that in detail.....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you should not disable the option of **editing Shipping address** , because when customer change address, than they need to enter new shipping address, if there is no option to enter Shipping address, than i doubt he will create new account to buy the product, it will affect your orders.

Comment: Thanks.
I have one more question - I am using subscription extension for certain product, like 3moths and six months and want to integrate reward points extension for the customer who buys the subscription for the first time.But am unable to understand how this flow will work